# client-server data storage

Tags: sql, database, client-server

My application must be client-server. The data is stored in the DBMS on the server. Upon request from the client, the DBMS returns a set of records. The program receives the data, and stores it in the model (data array) of the table. At some point, the user decides to add 10,000 rows to the table. At the same time, no requests to the DBMS occur, not pressed on the save button. At some point the power is turned off, no matter how, but the computer will be turned off, while the data is still in memory. The question is how these data will not be lost:

1. Make a sql request to update the data immediately
2. Write data to the local database. When you click on the button, the data is read from the local database and written to the server.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157866/best-practise-of-using-localstorage-to-store-a-large-amount-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

**Here are another two options to choose from:**

1. Save your JavaScript objects to the browsers local storage (not session storage) and delete it once you saved to the database. otherwise next time you open the application load from local storage if there is data.
2. Save your JavaScript objects to a JSON file on the server and also delete it once you saved the data to the database...